# How to convert an array into an arraylist of string arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to convert a string array into an arraylist. However, when I use this code to print the list, it returns values like this @3fec1b24. Could anyone help me with this?

```
ArrayList<String[]> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
dataRow = new String[nc];
dataList.add(dataRow);
```

Comment: To print the contents of an *array*, use `Arrays.toString(arr)` instead of relying on the default implementation of the `toString()` method on array instances.

Comment: BTW: `ArrayList<String[]>` is a list *of* arrays, so what's that got to do with converting array to list? If you want the strings in the `dataRow` array to be added to a list, declare the list as `ArrayList<String>` then do this: `dataList.addAll(Arrays.asList(dataRow));`

Comment: @janos If I use Arrays.toString(dataRow), the add method does not work. It throws the error
The method add(String[]) in the type ArrayList<String[]> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: @Andreas I want to convert it into a list of arrays

Comment: if you have string array like this `String[] strArray = {"AAA"}`, Then use `List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(strArray));` , You can change it as the dimension you want.

Comment: It's because you add dataRow address as first element to datalist array.